# r2 is completely off when trying to calculate predicted r2 using press statistics

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, regression

I am trying to calculate the predicted r2 (using https://gist.github.com/benjaminmgross/d71f161d48378d34b6970fa6d7378837), but the values are completely off. Even the standard r2 is not correct.

Using the metric r2, I get 0.8191

Using the benjamin gross method I get:
r2 = -19322.08 and pred_r2 = -35204.34

Here is scripts and dataset:

```
y_true = np.array(y_test) 
xs = X_test

def press_statistic(y_true, y_pred, xs):
    res = y_pred - y_true
    hat = xs.dot(np.linalg.pinv(xs))
    den = (1 - np.diagonal(hat))
    sqr = np.square(res/den)
    return sqr.sum()

def predicted_r2(y_true, y_pred, xs):
    press = press_statistic(y_true=y_true,
                            y_pred=y_pred,
                            xs=xs
    )

    sst  = np.square( y_true - y_true.mean() ).sum()
    return 1 - press / sst
 
def r2(y_true, y_pred):
    sse  = np.square( y_pred - y_true ).sum()
    sst  = np.square( y_true - y_true.mean() ).sum()
    return 1 - sse/sst

print(r2(y_true, y_pred))
print(predicted_r2(y_true, y_pred, xs))
```

y_test

```
16698    -7.758248
16699    -8.007173
16700    -8.226193
16701    -8.459754
16702    -8.348888
   
27754   -55.125691
27755   -55.217113
27756   -55.295972
27757   -55.303383
27758   -55.442200
Name: logger, Length: 11061, dtype: float64
```

y_pred

```
array([[ -7.21622871],
       [ -7.43596746],
       [ -7.58752355],
       ...,
       [-42.42983352],
       [-42.38907826],
       [-42.31012853]])
```

X_test

```
         DayCos   YearCos  ...  lagged_logger106  lagged_logger107
16698 -0.279829  0.836961  ...          2.294633          2.272826
16699 -0.021815  0.837353  ...          2.158491          2.294633
16700  0.237686  0.837744  ...          2.027501          2.158491
16701  0.480989  0.838135  ...          1.745879          2.027501
16702  0.691513  0.838526  ...          1.501611          1.745879
        ...       ...  ...               ...               ...
27754 -0.692563  0.486713  ...        -44.717439        -44.702282
27755 -0.855665  0.486086  ...        -44.918132        -44.717439
27756 -0.960456  0.485460  ...        -45.132487        -44.918132
27757 -0.999793  0.484833  ...        -45.458775        -45.132487
27758 -0.970995  0.484206  ...        -45.672997        -45.458775

[11061 rows x 227 columns]
```

Can you see, what I am doing wrong? Thx!
As I added the y_pred, I realised the arrays are different.. maybe that is why?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the `Hat matrix (h)` is defined as:

```
hii = X(X'X)X'
```

and the PRESS statistic is given as:

```
press = sum((ei/1-hii)2), where the sum runs from i=1 => nth observation
```

I recommend two things to do:

1. Check if the `hat = xs.dot(np.linalg.pinv(xs))` values in your `press_statistic()` function is actually equal to h<sub>ii</sub>
2. Try to `add_constant` in your least square model or ensure your linear regression model has an `intercept` in order to make an accurate estimation of the total sum of squares `(SST)`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your feedback! Making me look closer at y_pred, made me see that I was comparing an array and and array of lists. I there for had to reshape the array matrix (`y_pred_press = y_pred.reshape(1,-1)[0]` ) and it worked!
I don't know, why I didn't catch that in the beginning, but thx for making me.